# Android graph animation using canvas

Tags: android, animation, canvas, graph, colors

I am trying to animate my graph, which means that the graph curve can be seen getting drawn. The graph looks something like this:

[image]

Currently, I am able to animate the graph using below code:

```
        public void startAnimation() {    
        // Measure the path
        PathMeasure measure = new PathMeasure(mAnimationPath, false);
        length = measure.getLength();

        ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(EmotionsGraphView.this, "phase",  1.0f, 0.0f);

       animator.setDuration(1000);
       animator.start();
       }
    }


 //is called by animtor object
public void setPhase(float phase) {

Log.d("pathview", "setPhase called with:" + String.valueOf(phase));
mAnimationPaint.setPathEffect(createPathEffect(length, phase, 0.0f));
                    mAnimationPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
                    invalidate();//will calll onDraw
                }

private static PathEffect createPathEffect(float pathLength, float phase, float offset) {
return new DashPathEffect(new float[]{pathLength, pathLength},
                            Math.max(phase * pathLength, offset));
}
```

And inside my onDraw method:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
canvas.drawPath(mAnimationPath, mAnimationPaint);
}
```

I have below queries regarding this:

1. I am not able to set colors for the individual part of curve, ie. Yellow for topmost part of curve, green for the second part etc. 
   I have tried setting the color but the whole graph is picking the last set color and it's getting drawn only in the last set color ie. Blue in my case.
2. I am not able to set the dotted style in the graph.

Can someone help in this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need one path for each color/line style. If you have multiple paths (the second path starts at the endpoint of the first path to make a smooth transition) you can set a different paint and therefore a different style for each path.

Comment: So it means, an array list of path and paint? And inside _onDraw()_ I need to run a loop to get the _path_ and _paint_color_ ? Will that help. Please suggest.

Comment: yep - that would be a solution

Comment: This solution is not working.. Graph is still getting drawn with the last set color.

Comment: do you pass the right paint as parameter? `drawPath(Path path, Paint paint)`

Comment: Yes. I have created a separate class for _path_ and _paint_.  I am adding the object of this class in an arraylist. And inside _onDraw()_ method, I am traversing the array list and drawing the graph. But it's not working. :(

Comment: hmm... in my project I used a list like this and it works fine.. I'm sorry